# Loop through all named ranges in a Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to loop through all named ranges in my sheet.
I am currently doing this:

```
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
```

The problem is that this sheet has names with global scope and with sheet scope.
This loop only gets the global scope.
I've tried:

```
For Each nm In Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Names
```

But couldn't make it work. This loop also only gets those named ranges with global scope. Ideas?
I know the best solution would be to change the scope of the name, but I can't do it.

Comment: Could not replicate your issue. Got local and global Names without hassle.

Answer (score 7):

Could make it to work today. To post here, I made my problem much more simple, but this wasn't a good idea.

What I really do is to import some values from a sheet (selected with application.getopenfilename and opened with workbooks.open).
So I loop through all names in this "imported" sheet and import the values of those ranges to ranges with the same name in my original sheet.

```
for each nm in thisworkbook.names
    if left(nm.name, 5) = "campo" then
        'here I make my copy
    end if
next nm
```

Turns out that when you have a name with sheet scope, nm.name returns something like this:

```
 nameOfSheet!nameOfField
```

So I could never get in to that if. To solve my problem I used the following line. Thank you all for trying to help me.

```
currentName = Mid(nm.Name, InStr(1, nm.Name, "!") + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim nmTemp As Name

For intCounter = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
   MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Names(intCounter)
Next intCounter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Obj as Variant
For Each Obj In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(Obj.Name, "ExternalData") > 0 Then
        Obj.Delete
    End If
Next Obj
```

Refining hend's answer, we can use InStr to determine if a string is within the name range's name, which works for both local and global scope name ranges