# Loop over all the values of the named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a number of named ranges within the scope of my `Workbook`.

[image]

Now I want to loop over each named range by following the second answer of this related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234134/loop-through-all-named-ranges-in-a-excel-sheet)

```
Sub Range1()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Names(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

This macro shows me all the names such as `C_1` in a msgbox. I modify the script in the following way to "call" each of the ranges based on the name of the corresponding range.

```
Sub Range2()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim nm As Name
Dim rng_name As String

For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
   Set nm = ActiveWorkbook.Names(i)
   rng_name = nm.Name
   Set rng = Application.Range(nm.Name)           `This line yields an error
   MsgBox rng.Address
Next i

End Sub
```

The error I get is:

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_ Apolication failed

Any idea what I am doing wrong? If I inspect the elements I see that `rng_name` is equal to "C_1".

**EDIT**

I believe that it has something to do with how the named ranges are created. This is done in the following way:

```
Sub createRanges()

Dim LastRowAll As Long, LastRowUnique As Long
Dim x, y
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng_name As String

LastRowUnique = Sheets("Lists").Range("J2").End(xlDown).Row
LastRowAll = Sheets("Deribit").Range("D8").End(xlDown).Row

For Each x In Sheets("Lists").Range("J2:J" & LastRowUnique)
    For Each y In Sheets("Deribit").Range("D8:D" & LastRowAll)
        If y.Offset(0, -1).value = "Call" Then
            If rng Is Nothing And y = x Then
                Set rng = y.Offset(0, -2)
            ElseIf y = x Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, y.Offset(0, -2))
            End If
        Else:
        End If
    Next y
    rng_name = "C_" & x.Offset(0, -1).value
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rng_name, RefersTo:=rng.Address
    Set rng = Nothing
Next x
```

Comment: `Set rng = nm.RefersToRange`

Comment: Strange, for me the second code works quite ok.

Comment: @tigeravatar; if I inspect `nm` I see that it has the following error `Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: @Vityata is it possible that there is something wrong with my defined ranges?

Comment: @tigeravatar I came back to the same solution as the simplest approach, since the Sheet names being attached to the string `nm` appears to be the issue, though I believe that you could use `strLoc = InStr(nm,"!") // nm = Right(nm,len(nm)-strLoc))` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
    Set nm = ActiveWorkbook.Names(i)
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(nm.Name) 'This is where the error was
    MsgBox rng.Address
Next i
```

I also dropped the rng_name, since you didn't use it.

---

**Edit1:**

I was unable to get `Application.Range(nm.Name)` to work originally, but was able to get `ActiveWorkbook.Range(nm.Name)` to work, using ranges on different sheets named "c" and "d".  I noted that `nm = ActiveWorkbook.Names(i)` *did not* include the sheet name when it was recorded.

When naming ranges with the underscore and number in them (I tried c_1 & c_2) I was unable to get my code to work; on inspecting `nm` in debug mode, I noticed that it also listed the sheet name.  I had to specify that than rng would `.RefersToRange` to get the cell address to show up without the sheet name.

I did two additional checks, one with the underscore without number (used "d_") and another with a number and no underscore (used "name2"), and both **did** give me the same error.  Both scenarios kept the Sheet name in the string `nm`.

Here is the testing code that I was executing/stepping through to sort that out:

```
Dim rng As Range, i As Long
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
    Set nm = ActiveWorkbook.Names(i)
    'Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(nm.Name)
    Set rng = nm.RefersToRange
    'Debug.Print rng.Address
    MsgBox rng.Address
Next i
```

Using `Set rng = nm.RefersToRange` worked in all scenarios, while alpha-character only names worked with the `Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Names(nm.Name)`.

Suggestion, stick with `.RefersToRange` as the robust code.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, your code doesn't work. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my defined ranges?